# Why does one work with the Lagrangian density in field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, locality

Why is it necessary to introduce the Lagrangian density (integral of the Lagrangian over volume) when describing the dynamics of fields? Is there a specific reason for that or just for convenience?

Comment: The Lagrangian is the integral of the Lagrangian density over volume, not vice versa. Which is the one you think is being introduced unnecessarily?

Comment: Yes sorry, if I understand correctly, the lagrangian has the energy dimension (L=T-V), but in QFT, one works with $L$ defined as L = $\int$ $L$ dv, so my question is why?

Comment: @StackExchanger Actually, in QFT one works with the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$, where $S = \int L \text{d}t = \int \mathcal{L} \text{d}^4 x$. The volume integral of the Lagrangian density yields the Lagrangian you're used to work with (that's why it is called Lagrangian density). The Lagrangian still has units of energy, but the Lagrangian density has units of an energy density (i.e., energy per volume)

Comment: There are some theories that don't have a local Lagrangian density but studying them is hard. There are also some theories that do have a local Lagrangian density but studying them without exploiting this fact is hard. Both types appear in nature.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3903/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the question is about why in field theory the Lagrange density is preferred against the Lagrange function used in classical mechanics.

So if is the case, the reason is simple. The action as an integral over the Lagrangian has to be Lorentz invariant, using the Lagrange density this can be achieved, whereas with the Lagrange function of classical mechanics it cannot be achieved.

The goal is to get the integral of the Lagrangian (which defines the action)  to be Lorentz-invariant:
$$S=\int dt\, d^3x\, \mathcal{L}.$$
The 4-volume $dt\,d^3 x$ is Lorentz invariant (but a simple $dt$ is not Lorentz invariant), and if $\mathcal{L}$ is (and it can easily be) constructed as scalar built out of fields, the whole integral and therefore the action are Lorentz invariant.

The 4-volume $dt\,d^{3}x$ can be written in Lorentz-covariant way using the totally antisymmetrical Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$:
$$dt\,d^{3}x = \frac{1}{4!}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\,dx^{\mu}\,dx^{\nu}\,dx^{\rho}\,dx^{\sigma}.$$
This formalism is based on Minkowski space-time.  So curved space-time is not included here.

Comment: This is true, but there are many reasons to talk about a classical field that is not Lorentz invariant (e.g. reaction-diffusion equations, which can depend on $(\nabla \phi)^4$

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the fundamental thing is the *action* $S = \int dt L(q, \dot{q}, t)$. The Lagrangian should always be thought of as an ingredient for defining actions.

The Lagrangian density is the most natural way to describe a field, i.e. something that varies in space. A way of motivating this from the original Lagrangian formalism is to think of the field on a *lattice*:
$\phi( a n_i \mathbf{e}_i, t) \sim \phi_{n}(t)$, where $a$ is the lattice spacing and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^3$, and you should regard the $\phi_n$ as ordinary dynamical variables. If the fields extend through a 3x3 cube of side $d$, then there are $N = (d/a)^3$ variables. The Lagrangian is now a smooth function $\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$. This is a bit unwieldy, however we expect $L$ to take a somewhat special form on the basis of the universe's translation symmetry:

$L(\{\phi_n(t), \dot{\phi}_n(t)\}) = \sum_n \left[\mathcal{L}_0(\phi_n,  \dot{\phi}_n) + \mathcal{L}_1(\phi_n, \phi_{n+a\mathbf{e}_i}, \dot{\phi}_{n}, \dot{\phi_{n+a\mathbf{e}_i}}) + \ldots \right]$
where $\mathcal{L}_1$ depends on nearest neighbours, $\mathcal{L}_2$ depends on second nearest neighbours and so on. Crucially, none of the $\mathcal{L}$'s depend on where they are evaluated - there is no $n$ index on them - they only care about the value of the field at that point.
A basic assumption of field theory is that fields are *local* - the energy of a given field configuration should depend only on what that field is doing at a point $\mathbf{x}$, i.e. the energy at a point should depend only on the value of $\phi$ and its deformations.

Now observe that these dependencies on nearest neighbours can be thought of as discretised derivatives:
$$a \mathbf{e}_i \cdot \nabla \phi_n = \phi_{n+a\mathbf{e}_i} - \phi_n$$
It can be shown with a little work that you need to account for $n$th nearest neighbours to get the full $n$th order derivative. (Aside: This provides some intuition for why Taylor series work - if you know all [discrete] derivatives of an analytic function at a point, you can determine the function's value at any point and vice versa).

In the continuum $a \to 0$ limit, this should manifest as $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla \phi, \dot{\phi}, \nabla \nabla \phi, \nabla \nabla \dot{\phi},...) $. In principle, there is no reason *a priori* to truncate the series, indicating dependence on all derivatives of $\phi$. Likewise, the sum becomes an integral: $\sum_n \mapsto \int d^3 \mathbf{x}$, and we end up with

$$ L(\phi \text{ at all points in space}) = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \mathcal{L}(\phi(\mathbf(x)), \partial^\mu \phi(\mathbf{x}), \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \phi(\mathbf{x}),  ...)$$

and ultimately, the more relativity-friendly object

$$ S[\phi] = \int d^4\mathbf{x} \mathcal{L}(\phi(\mathbf(x)), \partial^\mu \phi(\mathbf{x}), \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \phi(\mathbf{x}),  ...) $$

In practice, Lagrangians in particle physics do not depend on higher order derivatives than $\dot{\phi}, \nabla \phi$, for various theoretical reasons. However, some classical Lagrangians in condensed matter do!

In short, the Lagrangian density is used to formalise the notion that the energy depends only on the fields, i.e. that the laws of physics are the same everywhere.

Comment: > In practice, Lagrangians in particle physics do not depend on higher order derivatives ... for various theoretical reasons

Would you have a source for these theoretical reasons?

Comment: This is [Ostrogradsky instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability), the statement that the vacuum becomes unstable if L depends on more than second order derivatives.